# MVC Getting Management approval

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I have just started looking into .net MVC and I really like it.
There are a few developers within our team who think the same. But before we are allowed to use it for any project we need to get the approval of management.

What would be the best way to convince management(which know little about programming) that this would worth while and it could have some cost benefit?

My belief is that it will force us to write better more accessible sites which are a lot more testable than web forms. Which in return would mean less bugs and higher customer satisfaction. But I have no evidence of this.

EDIT:

We have a team meeting in 4 days, this is where I will be making my pitch to the team and management.That gives me two weeks to learn more on MVC and do a presentation.

Comment: Why on earth are management who know little about programming making this sort of technology decision?

Comment: Why on Earth are any management allowed to make decisions? Any decisions? ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm a manager.  Fortunately, I still have technical chops.  There are some of us around.  :)

Comment: somewhere, a manager who does not know IT has to allow that the worktime is used for this, instead of timecritical current projects (and projects where business thinks that brings money are allways timecritical and very important... in their minds :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I'm a manager.  I've been one for more than 10 years.  Luckily, I've been able to stay very current with my technology passions, so I think I can speak from both sides of the fence.

Managers are going to be concerned with three things here:  risk, cost, and the status quo.  So, when you present your plan, you're going to need to address each of these:

*Risk:*

Explain to them that the risk here is very low.

MVC2 is just an extension of MVC, both of which has full source code available (management speak:  if we find a problem, we don't need support.  We can fix it ourselves).

There's a ton of community support.  (management speak:  I can go online and get answers to any questions I have in a matter of minutes).

Heavy-hitters at Microsoft are pushing this (management speak:  Microsoft is encouraging their developers to use this technology).

*Cost*

Talk about the fact that the technology is free, with a ton of community support.

Be ready to talk about ramp-up costs for any developers that don't have MVC experience.  They're going to be less productive at first.  Let your manager know that the developers will come up to speed quickly, and that MVC provides more efficient coding approach than traditional web forms.

Be ready to talk about costs and risks associated with ongoing maintenance.  If you've already got a ton of web forms out in the wild, this will present a second skillset that developers will need to maintain.  Find ways to convince management that it will be possible to maintain this skillset.

*Status Quo*

Many people become managers because they want a level of security and control in their life.  If this is the case with your manager, they'll be interested in maintaining a comfortable status quo, and not making significant changes.  If that's true here, you need to make the case that this really isn't a major change from what's being done today.  Assure them that you have a back-out strategy.  Talk about how this is really a proof-of-concept for MVC use in your organization, and that management will have an opportunity to review the success of the project prior to you ever suggesting MVC become a standard.

Answer (score 2):

Really what it comes down to is the fact that ASP.NET MVC forces developers to write better, more scalable, and easier to test code. It moves them away from the crapshoot that webforms often can be, and in a direction oriented toward quality architecture and good clean code that follows more rigid conventions.

One definite drawback of MVC is that the View structure required by the webforms view engine (default) encourages you to write spaghetti code in the views that is, at times, a nightmare to maintain. Given this fact, you might even want to pitch them with the new [Razor View Engine](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) that was recently announced. With it you can write some extremely clean view code that even the non-developers at your company could manipulate without bringing mass death and destruction to your application. Compared to the markup in the webforms view engine, Razor's markup is pretty much beautiful.

Also, check out [this really solid blog post](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2010/02/17/why-i-love-asp.net-mvc.aspx) by my buddy Matt Hidinger which does a great job of breaking down why MVC is so awesome.

When you speak to management just be sure to emphasize the all good points mentioned so far, and then compare them to all the bad that webforms is/can be. Be practical and realistic; if you have enough people on your team that are ready to jump on board with MVC then it's pretty much the best possible decision you can make, in my opinion, anyway. You may even want to take a moment to show them some of the great sites that use it- like Stack Overflow.

Personally, I have launched about 15 separate sites built with ASP.NET MVC and as such I feel I have a pretty solid understanding of it. I can wholeheartedly tell you, from my experience, MVC is the best thing that ever happened to ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you're comparing it to, but assuming it's an alternative to webforms, a few items to mention:

- better testability
- more control over output, which can help target other devices
- leverage existing knowledge of .net

Answer (score 0):

MVC framework encourages you to write more structured, testable and, as a result, more maintainable code. As the biggest costs in development are in the debugging and maintenance, those benefits alone should be a good validation. That said, it's still possible to code crap in MVC and that shouldn't be overlooked. If your company has a lot of expertise in another development framework then you really need to address the deficiencies in that and how MVC can rectify those deficiencies.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking up blog sites that support MVC and compiling some of the advantageous features of MVC.  I would start with Scott Guthrie's initial blog post regarding MVC - it outlines some great features - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/14/asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at trying to bring MVC in and need to convince management of the value, your best approach is too show how it can reduce long term support costs. Having an application that has well developed unit tests with decent code coverage can ensure quality over the life cycle of the application because you can higher level of confidence that changes you introduce have not broken pieces of the application. This doesn't negate the need to test the application, but you will find breaking changes faster. An approach utilizing MVC over MVC is a much more flexible platform for this testing.

There are many studies you can utilize that show the long terms support/maintenance costs of an application are often greater than the initial development costs. Stephen McConnell's [Code First](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) has a good discussion of this.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to what? Management would rather you wrote poorly-designed code? I'm surprised it's even an issue, in that whatever else they're asking you to do, by the current state of the industry, is self-evidently the wrong decision. If they know what MVC is, I can't see how any reasonable person would want you not to use it.

Comment: There will see it as not broke.Since work is getting done. As the saying goes if it aint broke don't fix it. There will also worry about the learning curve of the other developers.

Answer (score 0):

Sell it as an ASP.NET component, only made by Microsoft to incorporate some of the newer web 2.0 technologies moving forward. Tell them it will enhance maintainability while reducing development time. Tell them it uses existing infrastructure, and is more performant. Tell them it uses existing investments in training and software. Tell them it is more efficient, and makes it easier to fix issues and build enhancements. Tell them they'll get more out of their development team without allocating more resources.